# Consider $A=\bar B\subset C[0,1]$. Then which are TRUE?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Consider $A=\bar B\subset C[0,1]$ , where, $$B=\left\{f\in C^1[0,1] :|f(x)|\le 1,|f'(x)|\le 1,\forall x\in [0,1]\right\}.$$

Then, $A$ is

**(a)** Closed.

**(b)** Connected

**(c)** Compact

**(d)** Dense.

> ***My Attempt:***
>
> (a) TRUE. Since closer of any set is always closed. So $A$ is closed.
>
> (c) The set is bounded , but $C[0,1]$ is NOT finite dimensional. So how we can test whether the set is compact or NOT ?
>
> (d) I have No  idea about denseness.
>
> (b) TRUE. We can easily show that the set $B$ is convex subset of $C[0,1]$ and so $B$ is path connected, which implies connectedness of $B$ and hence $\bar B=A$ is connected.
>
> But, I have some confusion about my conclution of (b). We know that any convex subset of any Euclidean space is path-connected. Is it TRUE for any arbitrary space instead of Euclidean space?
>
> If it is TRUE then my conclusion about (b) is TRUE.

Suggest me about my conclusions..

Comment: What is the topology you consider on $C[0,1]$ ?

Comment: You are correct about b. $C^1[0,1]$ is a vector space, and convexity is easily defined the obvious way (pointwise, alternatively the parametrisation $(1-t)f+tg$ for the line between $f$ and $g$). You do have to prove (or at least point out) that every function on the "line segment" between is continuously differentiable.

Comment: @ Bebop): That was not given in the question. So we can assume the sup-norm topology on $C[0,1]$.

Comment: @ Arthur): Ok.I can prove it.But what about other options?

Comment: For $(c)$, think about Arzelà–Ascoli theorem and for $(d)$ look at the constant functions for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $B $ is path connected consider $f,g\in B$ then $||\lambda f+(1-\lambda)g||\leq |\lambda |||f||+|(1-\lambda)|||g||\leq 1$

Similarly check for $\lambda f^{'}+(1-\lambda)g^{'}$

$B$ is compact also by Arzela -Ascoli Theorem

and $B$ is obviously not dense consider $f(x)=2\in C[0,1]$ but cant be approximated by any member of $B$

Comment: ):Dense is NOT clear to me.

Comment: A set D is dense in X  if for any $x\in X$ we can find an element $d\in D$ very close to $x$.for $f(x)$ given can you find any such member from the set $B$ ?

Comment: @ learnmore ):I am NOT familiar with this definition of Dense set ? If you give details about it then it will be easy to me..

Answer (score 0):

The set B is not dense in C[0,1] as considering a tube of infinitesimal small width around f(x)=2 ∈ C[0,1] will not intersect B.